# Cannot recover Daedalus wallet after deleting on account of wallet not syncing

Tags: wallet, daedalus, seed-phrase

I sent ADA to Daedalus wallet. When opening the wallet, it took from 6:30 pm yesterday until around 4 am this morning to sync. I then deleted the wallet (since I have my recovery seed) and downloaded the update to see if anything happens. The sync took about 20 minutes but when I tried to recover the old wallet with my recovery seed, I got an error message. This happened on 4 occasions since this afternoon.

Also- I use Trezor model T as well but got an error message when trying to use that recovery process.  I used CAKE WALLET to exchange Bitcoin to ADA and sent it to Daedalus, originally. I do have the trade ID. Can anyone help or direct me to the proper resource?

Comment: I'm not sure I can help, but surely you should describe the error messages you received

Answer (score 1):

Enter your Daedalus-generated seed into [***Yoroi***](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/emurgos-yoroi-cardano-wallet/id1447326389) mobile wallet. It's a light wallet (a.k.a. SPV) so, there's no need to wait while it will be synced with the blockchain. Yoroi supports 15- and 24-word seeds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did. However, the ADA I exchanged is not there. The address is correct and it’s confirmed on the blockchain but it’s not in my balance. I don’t know what to do about this. The changenow support desk said I’d have to notify Daedalus support…..however I don’t know where to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure you wrote your mnemonic phrase down correctly, you should be able to restore it on any wallet. Try to use it on:

Yoroi, Adalite

If you can access the wallet from these services, the problem is definitely your Daedalus installation. You should proceed to reinstall it again, making sure to [clean all existing data](https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013170694-Uninstall-Daedalus-and-remove-wallet-s-data)